# How to ask about an explanation how something “functions”?

Tags: word-choice

I struggle with expressing my desire for an explanation how a particular physical thing works?

E.g. How does this clock work? How does a refrigerator function?

Best thing I can come up with is 「動き方」

Answer (score 2):

How about using the verb 「動く」 or the noun 「仕組み」...

> How does this clock work?
> 「この時計はどうやって動いているんですか。」

> How does a refrigerator function?
> 「冷蔵庫って、どういう仕組みになっているんですか。」